# Error when trying to install Ubuntu 14.10 Hyper-v VM from Virtual DVD .iso

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012, ubuntu-14.10

I'm trying to install a Hyper-v Gen 2 Ubuntu 14.10 Virtual Machine via a DVD .iso that I have attached as a virtual DVD on my Windows Server 2012 R2

First, two things that I know will be asked:

Yes I have Secure Boot disabled.
Yes I had the virtual DVD as the first boot device.

Everytime I connect and start the VM, I get a "the requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation" error.

This is my first try at installing a Gen 2 VM.  I have installed Gen 1 without issue.  I am not find very good documentation on this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

I ended up putting the .iso directly onto my Windows Server 2012 R2 hard drive and then pointing the virtual DVD on my virtual machine to the .iso image on the hard drive.

I guess I was being too literal about using the Physical DVD .iso location as my path for the Virtual DVD.  I can only surmise you cannot use a physical DVD as your Virtual DVD for installs.

Ubuntu 14.10 is now happily installed on my virtual machine.